# Can i update standard amount in opportunity from custom object

Tags: trigger, workflow

Whenever i create an opportunity record and add a "product" to that opportunity, "amount" field will be updated with productpricebook amount. amount is a readonly field in opportunity.

I want to do same using custom object and opportunity.

I am having a custom object "test" and another object opportunity.

In "Test" object i am having fields "Product(lookup)" and "Opportunity(lookup)".

In "test" object is child of product. whenever i select a lookup in test object and saves a record, product price must update in opportunity amount(which is readonly field).

Can i update readonly amount field with custom object product amount???

I tried to change it from developer console but since it is readonly field we can't edit directly. Please some one suggest a solution for it

Comment: Amount field by default is not ReadOnly. Maybe you set it as readonly for other reasons?

Comment: another question : If I understand, you want to update the opportunity amount  field with the product Price . Now:
1) With "update" you mean to clear old amount value and replace or to add the product price to the actual opportunity amount?
2) on test object,Which lookup you fill first? Product or Opportunity ? so you want that update fires when you fill the first or the second?

Comment: Amount field in opportunity is standard field when u create opportunity and 1 product to it, product price is updated there then edit the record u can see amount field as readonly.

Comment: ok reply to my second comment pls

Comment: this is for question u posted 2) I fill product 1st and select Opportunity and saves the record. then product pricebook amount must update in the opportunity amount . Both opportunity and product are mandatory field in custom object

Comment: for 1) No, i want to update(decrease/increase) amount based on products added from test object.

Comment: Ok, give me some minutes

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish this requirement would be a trigger

Comment: Can u pls guide me how can we do it with trigger just workaround for me so that i can complete it using trigger

Comment: the problem is that the Product object has not price, so how can you update opportunity amount? with which product field?

Comment: ya that is what i found just now. i found in schema builder i am having "Lookup Relationship from Price Book Entry to Product", can we get price values from there??

Comment: no, we can not go on pricebookentry (where you have the price) from the product. you can do vice versa, so this is a problem we cannot face until ou have product lookup on your test object..sorry

Comment: I didn't understood, r u saying to change the relationships???                      By changing which relationships we can achieve the task can u pls explain

Comment: See the following answer I posted to [Understand permissions on products, price books, and ideas](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/64839/2212). Perhaps it will provide some insight to the answer to your question. As @Tonio said, its PricebookEntry that contains what you want to get to, but the relationship is complicated.

Comment: Opportunity Amount is *sometimes* read only. If you have no Opportunity Line Items, it's an open currency field, while adding any products makes it operate like a read-only rollup-summary field. This technical nuance makes using Amount non-trivial for proper calculations. Thankfully, the new forecast features lets you forecast based on other fields, not just Amount, so you can have your custom object perform the task you're looking for.